# SQL or DQL, group by count since day begun, up until now

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

i am attempting to write a query that will select all "leads", and group them by hourly count for the current day.

Example:

```
lead 1: created today, 08.30
lead 2: created today, 09.30
lead 3: created today, 09.40
```

I need a result such as:

hour: 0, leads 0

hour: 1, leads 0

..

hour: 8, leads 1

hour: 9, leads 2

hour: 9, leads 2

hour: 10, leads 0

Needs to be since the day begun, this is what i have atm, but it is returning incorrect results.

```
SELECT HOUR(created) AS `HOUR`, COUNT(*)
FROM lead
WHERE created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY HOUR(created)
```

I am using symfony, so doing this with DQL is fine too.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is your table/data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
SELECT hrs.h AS `HOUR`, IFNULL(l.cnt, 0) AS lead_count FROM
(SELECT 0 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 11 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 12 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 13 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 14 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 15 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 16 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 17 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 18 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 19 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 20 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 21 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 22 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 23 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 24 AS h) hrs
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT HOUR(created) AS h, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM lead WHERE created >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') GROUP BY 1) l ON l.h = hrs.h
```